How to solve FileNotFoundError in Cookiecutter: Unexpected folder and missing file after choosing dependencies?
I'm trying to use cookiecutter as I've used so many times before, but now it keeps sending me an weird error message and creating a folder I've never seem before. I've tried searching in Cookiecutter issues, but found nothing.
This is the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ACER\anaconda3\Scripts\cookiecutter-script.py", line 9, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\ACER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1128, in __call__
return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1053, in main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1395, in invoke
return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 754, in invoke
return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cookiecutter\cli.py", line 140, in main
cookiecutter(
  File "C:\Users\ACER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cookiecutter\main.py", line 101, in cookiecutter
result = generate_files(
  File "C:\Users\ACER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cookiecutter\generate.py", line 352, in generate_files
generate_file(
  File "C:\Users\ACER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cookiecutter\generate.py", line 179, in generate_file
with io.open(outfile, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fh:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\Full_ML_Project\\{{ cookiecutter.project_name.lower().replace(' ', '_') }}\\config\\main.yaml"

This is happening after I chose between pip or poetry for dependencies. I've tried both and both gave me the same error message.
Also, it keeps creating a folder named {{ cookiecutter.project_name.lower().replace(' ', '_') }}
I've already tried searching on Cookiecutter issues, on stackoverflow and even talking to chatgpt, but nothing solve this issue
